# How to stop overflow on Vuetify app-bar content

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently creating a resume website, and I'm running into an issue of when I resize the screen to smaller sizes the buttons on the right side of the header start going off screen. How can I keep these items aligned to the right, without falling off screen? Also the margin between the two buttons is shrinking so they overlap one another.

Normal
[image]

Smaller screen
[image]

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar
    app
    color="primary"
    dark
    class="align-center"
  >
    <v-col>
      <v-btn
        plain
        dark
        :ripple="false"
        to="/"
        class="name">
        David Westwood
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>
    
    <v-spacer />
    <v-row align-center class="d-none d-sm-flex pl-2">
      <v-spacer />
      <v-btn 
        plain dark 
        v-for="directory in directories" 
        :key="directory[0]"
        :to="directory[1]"
        :ripple="false"
        >
          {{directory[0]}}
      </v-btn>
      <v-spacer />
    </v-row>
    <v-spacer />
    <v-row cols='8' align-content="right" no-gutters>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-col cols='2'>
        <v-btn
          class="white--text"
          href=""
          target="_blank"
          icon
        >
          <v-icon size="24px">
            mdi-linkedin
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols='6' class='mt-1'>
        <v-btn color='success'>
          Get in touch
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: ()=>{
    return {
      directories: [
        ["Resume", "/resume"],
        ["Portfolio", "/portfolio"],
        ["Contact", "/contact"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.v-btn.name {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Replace cols="6" with cols="auto" on Get in touch button. If it's set to a numeric value, the width will be fixed. If it's not included, the col will expand to fill the row.
- Remove v-spacer before LinkedIn (sibling inside v-row), add justify="end" to its parent v-row to align the content to the right.
- Three nav buttons in the middle need to be wrapped in v-col (each). Move the v-for to a v-col (preferably a cols="4" so they don't shift rows as the page narrows). v-row always needs v-col as immediate child.
- Also you have v-col and v-row as siblings, and the first v-col is not wrapped in the v-row.

Honestly you don't need ANY of those v-spacers. Just remove all of them and look into v-row justify properties. (space around, space between, etc.)

A trick to visualise content boxes is to add a style on all elements:

```
* {
  outline: 1px solid lime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Those worked perfectly. Also thanks for the help with the recommendation to learn justify. I had tried using align-content, because I thought it did what justify did and I ended up frustrated with it not working so I went to v-spacers.